# Pinterest Pin-it Button Options

Tags: javascript, pinterest

Could someone explain what data-pin-do & data-pin-config does and what the possible options are? I am not sure if I need to include them or just the anchor tag with href would work? Didn't find any documentation about it on the pinterest site either...

Thanks!

Comment: Not a real answer but... their [widget](http://business.pinterest.com/widget-builder/#do_pin_it_button) page will give different values for those attributes as you adjust the settings.